# why overwrite session in row new array codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

**row array['data'][1] save to session**

```
$ses['data'][1]['nama']= 'test';
    $set = $this->session->set_userdata('data',$ses);
    $get = $this->session->userdata('data');

    for ($i=0; $i < count($get); $i++) { 
        print_r($get);
    }
```

result

> Array
>   (
>       [1] => Array
>           (
>               [nama] => test
>           )
>   )

.
.
.

**problem when I row array['data'][2]**

```
$ses['data'][2]['nama']= 'test';
$set = $this->session->set_userdata('data',$ses);
$get = $this->session->userdata('data');

for ($i=0; $i < count($get); $i++) { 
    print_r($get);
}
```

**result  :**

> Array ( [2] => Array ( [nama] => test ) )

---

**I want result array is**

don't set ['data'][1] & ['data'][2] to save sesion in same time
but different time

> Array ( [1] => Array ( [nama] => test ) 
>   [2] => Array ( [nama] => test ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the array is getting overwritten.
Try combining your two elements into a single array and then feeding it in.

```
$ses=array(1=>array('nama'=>'test'),2=>array('nama'=>'test2'));
```

or if you want to merge the old session(s) with a new session...

```
// if later in the code, meaning $ses is already filled
$ses[2]['nama']='test2';  // new one
$set=$this->session->set_userdata('data',$ses);

// or if no $ses declared, you need to re-get
$ses[2]['nama']='test2';  // new one
$ses=array_merge_recursive($this->session->userdata('data'),$ses);  // merge with old one(s)
$set = $this->session->set_userdata('data',$ses); // set new combined array
```

It seems from my preliminary reading of documentation and examples that you can freely add new data on the first level of the array, but when you attempt to modify levels deeper than that, `set` focuses on the first level and ends up overwriting the previous subarray with the new one.

---

After some thought, my above attempt isn't efficient enough and `array_merge_recursive` is unnecessary.

```
$data_array=$this->session->userdata('data'); // retrieve session's current data subarray
$data_array[2]['nama']='test2'  // append new data to $data_array
$set_session=$this->session->set_userdata('data',$data_array); // set fresh array
$get=$this->session->userdata('data');  // retrieve new session data for checking
foreach($get as $g){
    print_r($g);  // check that session data is as expected
}
```

Comment: first i want insert ['data'][1] to session , next i want insert ['data'][2] to session, etc..
----------
don't set ['data'][1] & ['data'][2] to save sesion in same time
----------
and result: array['data][1] , ['data'][2],etc...

Comment: @Maxthinks does my `array_merge_recursive` method work for you?

Comment: yeah thanks you, this great method for merge array, thank yo @mickmackusa

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
$ses['data'][1]['nama']= 'test';
$this->session->set_userdata('data',$ses);
//$get = $this->session->userdata('data');
$ses['data'][2]['nama']= 'test';
$this->session->set_userdata('data',$ses);
$get = $this->session->userdata('data');
print_r($get);
```

**Output**

```
  Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [nama] => test
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [nama] => test
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: first i want insert ['data'][1] to session , next i want insert ['data'][2] to session, etc..
----------
don't set ['data'][1] & ['data'][2] to save sesion in same time
----------
and result: array['data][1] , ['data'][2],etc...